# Does Google Penalize Domains After DMCA's Approval

Tags: google, dmca

I read a blog post where the domain owner filed DMCA take downs against a domain however the domain Google approved the DMCA takedown against is still out ranking the domain they stole from.

Is the penalty Google hands out to bad domains only short term like a 1 month penalty?

Comment: Interesting blog post. I feel bad when someone from India do that :( Regarding DMCA notice, I think google just make the domain trust score value lower, other signals factor value will not going to change, and that's why torrent kind of sites still ranking, because there is no such a content that is targeting user intent, like `download blabla movie in 720p`

Comment: Me too. I think Google may penalize but its not permanent which is disappointing because these sites are still doing it and still ranking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that a single report won't have much effect, but repeated reports will

> ...(Google) will begin taking into account a new signal in our rankings: the number of valid copyright removal notices we receive for any given site. Sites with high numbers of removal notices may appear lower in our results.

https://search.googleblog.com/2012/08/an-update-to-our-search-algorithms.html